# How to pass String Parameters to Command objects in ADO with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ado

I have a function which returns a part of a SQL query.

```
Function GetYQConditions(command, startYQ, endYQ)
    Dim strSql

    strSql = " AND yq>=? and yq<=?"

    command.Parameters.Append(command.CreateParameter(undefined, 200, 1, 61, startYQ))
    command.Parameters.Append(command.CreateParameter(undefined, 200, 1, 61, endYQ))

    GetYQConditions = strSql    
End Function
```

**Problem:** The issue is `yq>=? and yq<=?` needs to have parameter passed as a string.

**Expected:** `yq>='startYQ' and yq<='endYQ'`

**Question:** How the paramters can be passed as a String value? That is `paramter` within a single qoute `` ? Or am I on a complete wrong direction?

Comment: You're trying to pass the values of "startYQ" and "endYQ" to "strSql"?

Comment: yes. Value will be something like startYQ = 2014Q1, but I need startYQ= '2014Q1' instead.

Comment: Your example code says "yq>=" not "startYQ="? Are you trying to update the string "strSql" or you're trying to update the variable "startYQ" and "endYQ"?

Comment: Apparently question mark (?) is supposed to be replaced by the variable's value. I am updating the string "strSql".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
Function GetYQConditions(command, startYQ, endYQ)
    Dim strSql

    strSql = " AND yq>=? and yq<=?"
    startYQ = "'" & startYQ & "'"
    endYQ = "'" & endYQ & "'"

    command.Parameters.Append(command.CreateParameter(undefined, 200, 1, 61, startYQ))
    command.Parameters.Append(command.CreateParameter(undefined, 200, 1, 61, endYQ))

    GetYQConditions = strSql    
End Function
```

Comment: Actually your previous answer was more correct since I am trying paramterised query than dynamic (your current answer) to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Does it work then? I see you're passing to a stored procedure, it was just unclear in your how you wanted it to behave.

Comment: Being new to this I guess I did lack a good explanation for what I was looking for. However, it did work. Thanks.